# How to add quantity field and add to cart button in a custom template?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, plugins, woocommerce

I am creating a custom woocommerce template and I need to display the quantity field as as well as the add to cart button.

I have used 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' however there seems to be no woocommerce styling applied and when I add the item to cart no woocommerce messages appear however if I go to another woocommerce archive page the message will be there which is obviously the wrong place.

Comment: You can try asking this at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The wordpress SE no longer allows third party plugin questions

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in two ways:
If you want to print only input (product quantity), use this:

```
<?php
woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
    'min_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 1, $product ),
    'max_value'   => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $product->get_stock_quantity(), $product ),
    'input_value' => ( isset( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? wc_stock_amount( $_POST['quantity'] ) : 1 )
) );
?>
```

It'll automatically create div with class *quantity* and input.

If you want to use WP hook to print qunatity input with add to cart button, use this:

```
<?php do_action('woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart'); ?>
```

If you want to do it in html (php only for get actual ID), here is example for you which is tested and it working:

```
<form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="quantity">
        <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Quantity" class="input-text qty text" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">

    <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add to cart</button>
</form>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php do_action('woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart'); ?>
```

This will add the quantity spinner and Add to Cart button.